Predicted hand tracking in Vision OS 2.0
I would like to know how predicted hand tracking works in ARKit. Does it use the Kalman filter, or does it have another approach, like machine learning?
I searched a lot but found no paper or website explaining how this prediction works.

Two antipodal aspects of a skeletal hand tracking are accuracy vs latency. When choosing any filtering/AI/solver algorithm, you sacrifice a low latency for a high accuracy, or vice versa. Kalman filter/predictor is optimal for both parameters. In this Disney research, the team used 22 individual Kalman Filters for each joint, which were working simultaneously. It's a shame that Apple very rarely publishes scientific papers about what principles its products or APIs are based on, however, I'm 99% sure it's the Kalman filter/predictor that's used in ARKit/RealityKit body tracking and hand tracking. Why reinvent the wheel?
I would like to add that when using the .predicted tracking mode, nothing can prevent Cupertino engineers from using a symbiosis of solutions: Kalman predictor (that uses past data to predict a joint's motion) with predictive AI models (when some joints occluded) with inverse kinematics based on specific solver.

The abundance of technologies used in skeletal hand tracking, on the one hand, increases accuracy, and on the other hand, produces latency=120+ ms.
